# How to write visible character count validation in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

(as a follow up to this question: [In Jquery AND Rails, how to get visible character count of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350909/in-jquery-and-rails-how-to-get-visible-character-count-of-a-string))

Let's say you have a string with embedded links and tags like so:

```
 This string has <a href="http://www.google.com">some links</a> inside it.
```

Then the visible string to a user is:

```
 This string has some links inside it.
```

The full string has 73 characters and the visible just 37 characters.

Let's say I now want to write a rails validation (custom validation) that checks the visible length of the string. ie:

```
 validate :string_visible_length

 def string_visible_length
      #some code that verifies the character length of a field named :field_name
 end
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I would need to strip the html tags and then check the character length..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could use the [strip links](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_links) method in your validation.

Make helpers available in your model file:

```
  include ActionView::Helpers
```

Here's the validation:

```
  validate :string_visible_length

private

  def string_visible_length
    visible_string = strip_links(self.column_name) # where column_name is the field you need validated
    errors.add(:base, 'Visible string is too long') if visible_string.length > 20 # 20 is whatever length you need
  end
```

Comment: with your code the error "undefined method `strip_links' for "<p>asdfasdfasdf</p>":String" comes up. Looked at the api, and you need to put the string in strip_links("this string"). But then switching to strip_links(self.column_name).length... leads to the error "undefined method `strip_links' for #<Model_name:0x00000104397358>" thoughts?

Comment: Oh yeah, duh, it's a helper method, not an AR call. Let me rewrite that.

Comment: hmm.. i think a line has to be added to the model along the lines of "      include ActionController::Base::Helpers" to the model (although I don't think this line works). Ideas?

Comment: Try it now by including the action_view helpers.